# How to make the user interface of Windows server stay active after disconnecting the server

Tags: windows, windows-server, user-interface

I'm facing the issues of losing user interface session of the server after disconnecting the server. The reason why I want to make the user interface session stay active is because I need to run some desktop app automation process in the server. But if I disconnect the server or minimize the server windows in connecting mode, it will lose the GUI and the desktop app automation process can't proceed.

Therefore, I would like to ask how to make the user interface session stay active even after we disconnect the windows server.

Comment: If the application is started through Scheduled Tasks, does it keep running? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I try using the Task Scheduler, eventhough my automation script run after disconnecting, but when it needs to interact with the desktop application, it failed. The user interface session seems like still unavailable